# why const variable can't be assigned to constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Why `x` can't be assigned to c2?

```
const double x = 65;
constexpr double x1 = 65;
const char x2 = 'A1';

// legal
constexpr char c1 = x1;
constexpr double c3 = x2;

// illegal 
constexpr char c2 = x;
```

Comment: In general, `const` does not guarantee that the value is available at compile time. Given `const_cast` it does not even guarantee that the value does not change.

Comment: Because your `x` is initialized to `65` at *runtime*, but your `c2` needs to know the value of `x` at *compile-time*, which is impossible.

Comment: @eike I agree with you, I added a another expression statement that is valid, and it's also a constant.

Comment: Notice that integral types are an exception, and `const int n = 65;` is considered as `constexpr int n = 65;`

Comment: @Jarod42 then why ``int x = 65;``,  ``const int a = x;`` and ``constexpr int b = x;`` behave differently?

Comment: `const int SIZE = 4; int arr[SIZE];` was legal in C++03 (before `constexpr` keyword from C++11). but constant should still be "compile-time" value to be use as-is. Non-const variable doesn't have such exception.

Comment: @DanielLangr can we initialize x with an int variable rather than an int literal ? will then ``const int x = 65`` will also be considered as ``consexpr int x = 65`` ?

Comment: @JituDeRaps See the first comment of Jarod42. You are asking about the same case.

Comment: @Jarod42 if that's the case , then given ``int x = 5;``. then why ``const int a = x;`` and ``constexpr int b = x;`` are behaving differently?

Comment: @JituDeRaps Because in this case, `const int a = x;` is not considered as `constexpr int a = x;`.

Comment: @eike: Not sure about your second sentence. The behaviour on attempting to change an object via `const_cast` that was originally declared as `const` is undefined. Your first sentence is the whole truth however.

Comment: @Bathsheba You're right of course. At that point anything could happen.

Comment: constant-initialized expressions are usable in constant expressions though

Comment: @Mechap no, they are not, try to compile statement as mentioned about

Comment: @JituDeRaps Then why does this work ?
```cpp
template <int N> struct X {};
const int a = 5;
template struct X<a>;
```

Comment: @Mechap because compiler consider it as ``constexpr int a = 5;``

Comment: @JituDeRaps According to [expr.const#2.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.2) and [expr.const#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4), a constant-initialized variable has to be initialized by a constant expression. Such variables can then be usable in constant-expressions.

Comment: @Mechap you can initialize a **constant** with any **literal value** or any other variable of its type but you can only initialize a **constant expression** with either a **literal value** or **constant expression** of its type.  And ``const int x = 4`` considered as ``constexpr int x = 4``.

Comment: @JituDeRaps As far as I know, an expression usable in constant expressions is not always itself a constant expression.

Comment: @Mechap yes , you are right . It's only when you initialize const int with a literal value.

Comment: @JituDeRaps Ok I think I get it now. However I still don't understand why expressions usable in constant expressions can be used to initialize non-type template parameters but not  to initialize constant expressions themselves. I mean they both need to be initialized with an expression whose value is known at compile time.

Comment: @Mechap only constexpr need a value that is known at compile time.

Comment: @JituDeRaps I though that since template instantiation occurs at compile time, template arguments must have compile time values.

Comment: @Mechap i don't know about that. I'm just a beginner.